# What is the best format to ask users to submit financial information

Tags: forms, design-patterns, input-fields, financial

I'm looking for an example of a simplified way of asking users to submit financial information in an online form for the following 4 categories e.g. income, commitments, assets and liabilities. Any tips please?

Comment: What have you made so far? How knowledgeable are your users when it comes to financial info?

Comment: You really need to provide more info to get a useful answer. Simplified compared to what? Who are your users, and what are the issues you are currently experiencing that you need to address?

Comment: Yes Peter Im a newbie at asking questions on stack exchange so I realise now that my question was too broad, thanks for providing the other parameters I should be thinking of.

Answer (score 1):

I really cannot understand completely the purpose or the business requirement, nevertheless let me provide overview in generic fashion -

1. Try to build all these information on one page without splitting them through wizard, as nobody likes to enter very detailed "numbers" since it requires lot of cognitive load to think and enter the data
2. Keep your questions to minimal and to the key importance alone, since people will be circumspect of entering asset details, since they would mostly think of somebody caches data intelligently and may even call them for some other investment or banking purposes
3. Provide clear field of entry, when entering numbers it should clearly mark the hundreds, thousand and million denominators without any doubts. All number related facts could be right aligned and total or gross sum can neatly appear at the bottom
4. Each of the section should be independent of editing and clearing the cells, if the data needs to be tweaked. (Depends on your business context)
5. Provide examples in case of technical jargon or help users to learn the forms easily.

Comment: Thanks @inkmarble for your answer. It was my very first question ever on stack exchange, so you did well in providing me with advice when I had, upon reflection asked a very broad question. I guess I had to start somewhere (no place better than jumping in the deep end) and in future I'll be better at refining exactly I'm asking. It was broad question I guess because I was at the beginning of the project.